# If $A$ is a nonempty subset of $R^d$ and $x$ is a point in $R^d$,then the distance $x$ to $A$ is $\mbox{dist}(x, A) = \mbox{inf}\{|x−y|:y \in A\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $A$ is a nonempty subset of $R^d$ and $x$ is a point in $R^d$,then the distance from $x$ to $A$ is
\begin{equation}
      \mbox{dist}(x, A) = \mbox{inf}\{|x−y|:y \in A\}
\end{equation}
Prove the following statements:

a) If A is closed, then $x \in A$ if and only if dist$(x, A) = 0$

b) dist$(x, A)\le |x−y|+$ dist$(y, A)$ for all $x,y \in R^d$.

c) |dist$(x, A)−$dist$(y, A)| \le |x−y|$ for all $x,y \in R^d$.

A set A is closed if $A^c=R^d-A$ is open. Another definition is: A is closed $\iff$ if $x_n \in A$ and $x \in R^d$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$, then $x \in A$. I am thinking this second definition's backward direction will be needed to prove a).

b) seems a bit trivial, since if $\mbox{dist}(x, A)=\mbox{inf}|x-y|$ then clearly it is less than or equal to $|x-y|$ by the definition of infimum. It doesn't even seem to be necessary to add $ \mbox{dist}$(y, A)$ to satisfy the inequality.

c) doesn't $\mbox{dist}(y,A)$ just become $0$, leaving $|x-y|\le |x-y|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Let $A$ be closed. If $d(x,A)=0$ then there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ with $d(x,a_n) \to 0$. But then $x \in A$ because $a_n \to x$  and each $a_n \in A$. Conversely, if $x \in A$ then $d(x,A) \leq d(x,x)=0$.

b) Your argument is false. $d(x,A) \leq d(x,y)$ hold only for $y \in A$.

$d(x,A) \leq d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)$ for all $a \in A$. Take infimum over $a$ to finish.

c) By b) $d(x,A)-d(y,A) \leq d(x,y)$. Interchanging $x$ and $y$ we get $d(y,A)-d(x,A) \leq d(x,y)$. Combine these two to get c).

Comment: Can you elaborate on part a) how you got "if $x \in A$, then $d(x,A)=0$? I don't see how you got that inequality

Answer (score 0):

Your idea for a is a good one.  One approach to construct a sequence $x_n \to x$ with $x_n \in A$ is to say that for each $n$, we take $x_n \in B_{1/n}(x)$ (where $B_r(x)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$).

For b, you seem to be assuming that $y \in A$. However, in this context, it is only given that $y \in \Bbb R^d$. You can answer this question using the triangle inequality.

The same is true for c, but this time you use the "backwards" triangle inequality.